# Using cp in bash to use piped in information about files like modification date

Tags: bash

I am trying to copy files from one directory into another from certain modification date ranges. For example, copy all files created after May 10 from dir1 to dir2. I have tried a few things but have been unsuccessful so far.

This made sense to me but cp does not take the filenames piped to it, but just executes ./* and copies all files in the directory:

```
find . -type f -daystart -mtime 2 | cp ./* /dir/
```

This almost worked, but did not copy all of the matching files, I also tried xargs -s 50000, but did not work:

```
find . -type f -daystart -mtime 2 | xargs -I {} cp {} /dir/

find . -type f -daystart -mtime 2 | xargs cp -t /dir/
```

Found this online, does not work:

```
cp $(find . -type f -daystart -mtime 2) /dir/
```

Ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Can you use `tar` instead?

Comment: FYI, the title of this question is misleading -- it makes it sound like you want `cp` to create files with metadata from stdin, rather than simply choosing files to operate on based on a list from stdin.

Comment: ...btw, see entry #1 in http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls re: the third ("found this online") attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given as your actual question is about using filenames from stdin rather than metadata from stdin, this is quite straightforward:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do
  cp "$filename" /wherever
done < <(find . -type f -daystart -mtime 2 -print0)
```

Note the use of `IFS= read -r -d ''` and `-print0` -- as NUL and `/` are the only two characters which can't be used in UNIX filenames, using any other character, including the newline, to delimit them is unsafe. Think about what would happen if someone (or a software bug) created a file called `$'./ \n/etc/passwd'`; you want to be damned sure none of your scripts try to delete or overwrite `/etc/passwd` when they're trying to delete or overwrite that file.

---

That said, you don't actually need to use a pipe at all:

```
find . -type f -daystart -mtime -2 -exec cp '{}' /wherever ';'
```

...or, if you're only trying to support GNU cp, you can use this more efficient variant:

```
find . -type f -daystart -mtime -2 -exec cp -t /wherever '{}' +
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify why the various attempts didn't work, so I can only assume that they are the result of whitespace in the filenames.

Try using `find`'s useful `-exec` action instead of using `xargs`:

```
find . -type f -daystart -mtime 2 -exec cp {} /media/alex/Extra/Music/watchfolder/ \;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -type f -daystart -mtime 2 \
| cpio -pdv /media/alex/Extra/Music/watchfolder/
```